# Convergence of the Integral of Random Functions

Tags: probability, integration, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of bounded real-valued random functions defined on $[0,1]$. Suppose that for each $x \in [0,1]$, $f_n(x)$ convergences in probability (or a.s.) to a number $f(x)$. Then does
$$ \int_{0}^1 |f_n(x) - f(x)| dx $$
converge in probability (or a.s.) to $0$?

---

This is not the dominated convergence theorem because $f_n$ is random, that is, for each $n$, $\{f_n(x)\}$ is a stochastic process indexed by $x$.

---

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I have not heard of a random function before. Are you talking about this: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Random_function ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I think that's right. I am basically trying to refer to a stochastic process.

Answer (score 1):

Partial ansswer: True for convergence in probability. I believe it is false for a.s. convergence since the null set in the hypothesis depends on $x$. (I don't have a counter-example yet).

Note that a uniformly bounded sequemce of r.v.'s $(X_n)$ converges in probability to $X$ iff $E|X_n-X| \to 0$. Now $E\int_0^{1} |f_n(x)-f(x)|dx =\int_0^{1} E|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx \to 0$ by two applications of DCT (one for the expectation and one for the integral). Hence $\int_0^{1} |f_n(x)-f(x)|dx \to 0$  in probability.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer! And I agree that the a.s. part is false.